# Turn series to dataframe with certain dimension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a series with 5 value

```
    0 A
    1 A
    2 B
    3 C
    4 E
```

And I have a dataframe A with n columns.

Is there any way I can make a dataframe that dimension is (5*n). All columns is made up by the series and column names are  the same as dataframe A?

For example:

dataframe A looks like

```
      col1    col2
0        1       3
1        2       2
2        2       2
3        2       6
4        4       2
```

and new dataframe looks like

```
      col1    col2
0        A       A
1        A       A
2        B       B
3        C       C
4        E       E
```

The best solution I came up with for now is to make a copy of A and use loop to change values of new dataframe column by column.

thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([s] * len(df.columns), 1, keys=df.columns)
print (df)
  col1 col2
0    A    A
1    A    A
2    B    B
3    C    C
4    E    E
```

Or if need faster solution use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) + [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
l = len(df.columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(s,l ).reshape(-1,l), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
print (df)
  col1 col2
0    A    A
1    A    A
2    B    B
3    C    C
4    E    E
```

Or simplier:

```
l = len(df.columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([s] * l), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
print (df)
  col1 col2
0    A    A
1    A    A
2    B    B
3    C    C
4    E    E
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

L = list('abcdefghijklmno') 
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(L, 100))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 100))).add_prefix('col')

print (df)

In [161]: %timeit pd.concat([s] * len(df.columns), 1, keys=df.columns)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.84 ms per loop

In [162]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(s.values,len(df.columns)).reshape(-1,len(df.columns)), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
1000 loops, best of 3: 199 µs per loop

In [163]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([s] * len(df.columns)), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1 ms per loop

In [164]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({k : s for k in df.columns})
100 loops, best of 3: 2.33 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame` constructor with a *dict* comp.

```
pd.DataFrame({k : df1.Col for k in df2.columns})

  col1 col2
0    A    A
1    A    A
2    B    B
3    C    C
4    E    E
```